# Python - overload same function with different arguments

Tags: python, overloading

I have got a function that sets features and want to have two versions of it. One takes all features and splits them into words and phrases and the second one receives already split words and phrases as arguments

```
def set_features_2(self, words, phrases):
    self.vocabulary = set(words)
    self.phrases = SortedSet(phrases)

def set_features(self, features):
    phrases = [f for f in features if ' ' in f]
    words = [f for f in features if f not in phrases]
    self.set_features_2(words, phrases)
```

What is the easiest way to remove this duplication? Both of them should be called "set_features" but both receive a different set of arguments.
I know that it is possible to use args and kwargs but it is an overkill for such as trivial case.

Comment: Have `words`, `phrases`, and `feature` parameters and give them default values of `None` then check to see what got passed before processing.?

Comment: or use the *args, **kwargs construct to allow accepting arbitrary arguments.

Comment: I dont think that it is the proper way of solving it. I would have to sent f(None, None, features) to send features... Args and Kwargs also seem to be overkill

Comment: Why do you want to overload the name?  The two methods have distinct functionality, with no real conceptual overlap in either data processing or linguistics.

Comment: I don't see a duplication problem; I just see a naming problem.

Comment: Method overloading would make sense, if the data you are giving could have different representations, but the outcome is the same. I don't see why you would want to use method overloading.

Comment: So should I give different name? set_features_by_phrases_and_words()?

Comment: ok, solved, it is a naming problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't overload function arguments per se, but you can emulate this behavior with keyword arguments. The slightly annoying part is that you'd have to handle the validity checks (i.e., that the user doesn't pass both `features` and `words` and `phases`). E.g.:

```
def set_features(self, features = None, words = None, phrases = None):
    if features: 
        if words or phrases:
            raise ValueError('Either pass features or words and phrases')
        else:
            phrases = [f for f in features if ' ' in f]
            words = [f for f in features if f not in phrases]

    self.vocabulary = set(words)
    self.phrases = SortedSet(phrases)
```

Comment: What about: `set_features(phrases=phrases)`? I think `SortedSet` accepts `None`, but `set` doesn't. That's assuming it makes sense to allow `None` at all...

Answer (score 1):

Python allows default arguments.

```
def set_features(self, features=None, words=None, phrases=None):
    if features is not None:
        phrases = [f for f in features if ' ' in f]
        words = [f for f in features if f not in phrases]

    self.vocabulary = set(words)
    self.phrases = SortedSet(phrases)
```

you could then call it with `set_features(features=features)` or `set_features(words=words, phrases=phrases)`